# Timeout::Error: execution expired when using webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webkit

I'm using Capybara/Rspec to perform some feature testing, I got by with the default rack_test driver that Capybara uses just fine, however, I can't seem to get the webkit driver to work using this guide: https://mattbrictson.com/running-capybara-webkit-specs-with-jenkins-ci

The command I'm using is as follows:
`DISPLAY=localhost:1.0 xvfb-run rspec spec/features/sample_spec.rb`

The result I get is this:

```
 Failure/Error: visit '/'
 Timeout::Error:
   execution expired
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.5.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:107:in `initialize'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.5.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:107:in `open'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.5.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:107:in `attempt_connect'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.5.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:101:in `block in connect'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.5.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:99:in `connect'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.5.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:26:in `initialize'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.5.1/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:17:in `new'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.5.1/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:17:in `initialize'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.5.1/lib/capybara/webkit.rb:11:in `new'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.5.1/lib/capybara/webkit.rb:11:in `block in <top (required)>'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:79:in `call'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:79:in `driver'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:65:in `initialize'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara.rb:248:in `new'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara.rb:248:in `current_session'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:46:in `page'
 # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
 # ./spec/features/sample_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My `visit '/'` code works perfectly with rack_test... what's the deal with webkit?

Comment: Please post your Capybara configuration.